# Animation for BottomNavigation Fragments with Architecture Navigation Components

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-components, bottomnavigationview

I have successfully integrated the bottom navigation with the latest android architecture navigation components. The following is my complete code.

1. Navigation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="in.zedone.bottomsample.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_saloons"
        android:name="in.zedone.bottomsample.ui.saloons.SaloonsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_saloon"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_saloons" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_offers"
        android:name="in.zedone.bottomsample.ui.offers.OffersFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_offer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_offers" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_account"
        android:name="in.zedone.bottomsample.ui.account.AccountFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_account"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account" />

</navigation>
```

2. BottomNavigationView

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     android:id="@+id/nav_view"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
     android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
     app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
     app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
     app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

3. MainActivity

```
BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
// Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
// menu should be considered as top level destinations.
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_saloons, R.id.navigation_offers,R.id.navigation_account)
                .build();
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
```

Now how can I add transition/animation on select each tab/fragment in bottom navigation?

Comment: Did you find a way to do that? The answer is not correct based on your question since you don't have actions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of using setupWithNavController function, follow this way.

First, create your NavOptions which include animation shown below.

```
val options = NavOptions.Builder()
            .setLaunchSingleTop(true)
            .setEnterAnim(R.anim.enter_from_bottom)
            .setExitAnim(R.anim.exit_to_top)
            .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.enter_from_top)
            .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.exit_to_bottom)
            .setPopUpTo(navController.graph.startDestination, false)
            .build()
```

Then use setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener to navigate with animation like that.

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.fragmentFirst -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentFirst,null,options)
            }
            R.id.fragmentSecond -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentSecond,null,options)
            }
            R.id.fragmentThird -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentThird,null,options)
            }
        }
         true
    }
```

Finally, you should prevent same item selection case so you can add below code.

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener { item ->
        return@setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener
```

I used bottomNavigation like that in my project to add animation for page transitions.
I hope it helped.

Comment: This is the only easy and bugfree solution i could find, works perfectly and should be the accepted answer. Just remember to remove "setupwithnavcontroller". Thanks!

Comment: Where do I get the animations from? "R.anim.enter_from" etc are all red"

Comment: Hi @Andrew, you can add anim folder into res directory and add your animations via searching with google then change names with yours.  For example: enter_from_bottom.xml should be

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="@integer/anim_duration"/>
</set>

Comment: @thegirlincode with above code, if I select a Fragment now and then after sometime if I select the same Fragment again then a new object Fragment is getting created instead of showing the old object of the Fragment, how can I achieve this??

Answer (score 4):

its work with BottomNavigationView's siblings fragment also(JetPack Navigation Components)

```
// FragmentA.kt
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

  exitTransition = MaterialFadeThrough()
}


// FragmentB.kt
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

  enterTransition = MaterialFadeThrough()
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some more details about the question the solution you expect.

Comment: This method is quite easy to implement. However, there is an obvious delay in fragment transitioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with keeping `setupWithNavController` by overriding `onCreateAnimation()` in each `Fragment` and checking whether or not you're entering or exiting the `Fragment` with the `enter` parameter and then creating the appropriate `Animation` with `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, animationId)`.

```
override fun onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int): Animation? {
    return if (enter) {
        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in)
    } else {
        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_out)
    }
}
```

EDIT as a response to iloo:

According to Material Design (https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#behavior) you shouldn't be doing that in the first place, but I guess it's still achievable.

Since when using `setupWithNavController` all destinations are top level there will
ever be only one `previousBackStackEntry` whose destination points to the home
destination, therefore `previousBackStackEntry` is not much of a help in figuring out which `Fragment` are you coming from.

Other approach could be to have a public variable in the `Activity`, where you will store the
last destination you were in and set that variable in each `Fragment` upon resuming.
And you can check that variable in `onAnimationCreate` to know which `Fragment` you're coming from
and apply an appropriate animation.

Comment: To me, this approach works well when animation does not depend on the item's position in bottom navigation menu, relatively to other items. Fading in and out works since it doesn't have direction. But if you want the views to slide in from left or right, and slide out to left or right, depending on its "position on the line of views", the incoming parameters are not enough. Can this approach be elaborated on to be used for cases like this?